# while installing boto3, getting access error

Tags: python, pip, boto3

I am trying to install boto3 in my VDI. But i am getting following error.

```
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.5->boto3) (1.12.0)
ERROR: requests 2.22.0 has requirement urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1, but you'll have urllib3 1.26.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: urllib3, botocore, s3transfer, boto3
  Found existing installation: urllib3 1.24.2
    Uninstalling urllib3-1.24.2:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3-1.24.2-py3.7.egg-info\\dependency_links.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have checked the path what it is giving , `c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3-1.24.2-py3.7.egg-info\\dependency_links.txt'` but empty notepad file is there.

Any leads will be helpfull.

Comment: You are probably running this command without administrative permissions that’s why it says “access denied” try using administrative permissions.

Comment: Yeah Rajat.  Nit it worked for me. I just given the command `pip install --user module/package_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you don't have admin access. That's why pip is not able to write in your system.

You can solve this very easily. There are 2 ways:

1. use `pip install boto3 --user`
2. Open the admin mode. In windows, run cmd as administrator, in Linux, run `sudo -i`